# How to find the limit by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to find the limit by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem:

$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{X},\mu)$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all singletons of the sequence $S=(\frac{1}{n})_{n=1}^\infty$, $\mu (\frac{1}{n})=n$ and $\mu (E)=0$ for $E \in \mathcal{X}$ if $E \cap S = \emptyset$

> $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\int \frac {(kx+1)^4}{k^4x+1}d\mu$$

Could you help to find $|f_k|\le g$:integrable

Comment: Where do you integrate?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to expand the term $(kx+1)^4$. You get

$$(kx+1)^4 = 1 + 4kx+6k^2x^2+4k^3x^3+k^4x^4$$

note that when you divide this by $k^4x+1$ the terms whose the power is less than 3 will die when you let $k \rightarrow \infty$

$$\frac{(kx+1)^4}{k^4x+1} = \frac{1 + 4kx+6k^2x^2+4k^3x^3+k^4x^4}{k^4x(1+\frac{1}{k^4x})} \rightarrow x^3$$ when $k \rightarrow \infty$.

To use the DCT you can use again the Binomial Theorem

$$\frac{(kx+1)^4}{k^4x+1} \leq \frac{1 + 4kx+6k^2x^2+4k^3x^3+k^4x^4}{k^4x}$$

Now your upper bound (and his existence) depends on where you will integrate those functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified bounds of integration I'll assume $[0,1]$. Write 
$$
  (kx + 1)^4
= \sum_{i=0}^4 \binom{4}{i}(kx)^i
= 1 + (kx)^4 + \sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{4}{i}(kx)^i
$$
so that 
$$
     \frac{(kx + 1)^4}{k^4x+1}
=    \frac{1 + (kx)^4}{k^4x+1} + \sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{4}{i}\frac{(kx)^i}{k^4x+1}
\leq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{4}{i},
$$
and this last term is integrable over $[0,1]$.